# My code is giving Codeunreachable error, why?

Tags: java

My code is giving error of code not reachable ,I have commented at the line where the value of
case2C is accepted from the user, I dont understand why?
first part is working fine where i have accepted three values but at the starting of second part where i have taken more 3 values from the use it gives the error ,why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class CookieClicker{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scase1C=new Scanner(System.in);
            int testcase1Case=scase1C.nextInt();
            double case1C=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double case1F=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double case1X=scase1C.nextDouble();

            double rem=case1X/2;
            double case1Farm1=case1C/2+case1X/(2+case1F);
            double case1Firstresult;

            while(true){
                if(rem>case1Farm1){

                    rem=case1Farm1;
                    case1Farm1=case1Farm1+case1C/(2+case1F)+case1X/(2+2*case1F);
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    case1Firstresult=rem;

                }

            }

            double case2C=scase1C.nextDouble();           here the error is coming saying unreachable code,
            double case2F=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double case2X=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double rem2=case2X/2;
            double case2Farm1=case2C/2+case2X/(2+case2F);
            double case2Firstresult;

            while(true){
                if(rem>case2Farm1){                                

                    rem=case2Farm1;
                    case2Farm1=case1Farm1+case2C/(2+case1F)+case1X/(2+2*case1F);
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    case2Firstresult=rem;

                }

            }
            double case3C=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double case3F=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double case3X=scase1C.nextDouble();
            double rem3=case1X/2;
            double case3Farm1=case3C/2+case1X/(2+case1F);
            double case3Firstresult;

            while(true){
                if(rem>case1Farm1){

                    rem=case1Farm1;
                    case1Farm1=case1Farm1+case3C/(2+case1F)+case1X/(2+2*case1F);
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    case3Firstresult=rem;

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While (true)  is causing it to loop forever. You use continue,  but that just ends that iteration of the loop. Ie: the loop will start from the nezt iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(true){
if(rem>case1Farm1){

    rem=case1Farm1;
    case1Farm1=case1Farm1+case3C/(2+case1F)+case1X/(2+2*case1F);
    continue;
}
else{
    case3Firstresult=rem;

}
```

Add break; after case3Firstresult = mem, else the loop will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
   if(rem>case1Farm1){
        rem=case1Farm1;
        case1Farm1=case1Farm1+case1C/(2+case1F)+case1X/(2+2*case1F);
        continue;
    }
    else{
        case1Firstresult=rem;
    }
}
```

The `while(true)` portion is causing the issue here. Replace `continue` with `break`, then have a rethink about the design of your code, and maybe incorporate the logic in your `if` statement into the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never leaves the "`while(true)`" block.  You need to use a `break` to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while(true)` loop above those statements. This loop will *never* exit unless `break` is called in it's body. Therefore, the statements after can never be reached. It looks like you want to call a `break` statement here:

```
else{
    case1Firstresult=rem;
    break; // add break
}
```

If this isn't the right place, then add the `break` somewhere else. But you have to have one in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of your

```
while(true)
```

which keeps going on continuously unless you break out of it.